# Why my image width changes even it is set to fixed with?

Tags: html, css

I have a html code that structured like this:

```
<div title="XYZ Tool" class="tbBtn toolbarBtn active xcLightBack tbBtnPressed" id="ctl_AAA_4_BBBTool" type="div" toolbarcoloropacity="1" toolbarcolor="#F1727F">

    <img class="eilXYZ" id="ctl_Vessels_4_ctl04" style="background-position: -114px 0px;" __imageClass="eilXYZ">
    <h4 class="normalFontSize noPointerEvents" style="padding-left: 4px; margin-top: -17px;">My TEXTTTT</h4>
</div>
```

when running from IE, the width of the image is 16.04px although in css class , I already defined the width to be 23px. Below is what I get from IE developer tool:
[image]

Why is that? When I add more text in H4, the width of the image also extends, but never reach 23px I defined...

Thanks!!

Comment: can you paste your full code please?

Comment: You have an `=` instead of `:` in your h4 style.

Comment: There is no such attribute as `background-image` on the `img` element.

Comment: background-image, must be under style tag. :S

Comment: the actual implementation of the <image> is as above, but in IE dev tool, it does show a property called "background-image", but it should not be related to the problem?

Answer (score 0):

instead of `width: 23px` change to `max-width: 23px`

Comment: A little explanation would be helpful.

Comment: by setting max-width means that your image width will be of maximum 23 px, not matter what.